# Set the parent context separately from the parent in QML components

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

When I define a `Component` in QML I can define a `alias property` to expose properties of `QtObjects` that are otherwise hidden by the `Components` root.

Especially interesting is the `default property alias` to build powerful reusable and adaptable `Components`. But there is no generic way to have alter the nameresolution, which is bad for properties and signals.

Example: MyComp1.qml

```
Item {
    id: rootItem
    default property alias content: childItem.data
    signal sig()

    Item {
        id: childItem
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
MyComp {
    id: myObj
    signal sig1()
    onSig1: console.log('here')
    Button {
        id: button
        onClicked: {
            parent.sig()
            parent.sig1()
        }
    }
}
```

Here `button` is now a child of `childItem`, but both signals: `sig()` and `sig1()` are defined in `rootItem`, which leads to an error. To the user of of my nicely designed `Component` it is not transparent. He would need to look in the code of the `Component` to realize, why the buttons parent is not `myObj/rootItem` but in fact of `childItem`. This might lead to bugs.

Therefore I am looking for a way to prevent it.
For signal `sig()` this would be possible by the modifying the `MyComp` and manually forward the signal from `childItem` to `rootItem`:

```
Item {
    id: rootItem
    default property alias content: childItem.data
    signal sig()
    Item {
        id: childItem
        signal sig()
        onSig: rootItem.sig()
    }
}
```

But is there a way to *shortcut* this, so that the user does not need to us `myObj.sig1()` but might use `parent.sig1()`.

Same goes for properties, that are added uppon instantiation:

```
MyComp {
    signal sig1()
    property int num: 5
    Button {
        text: parent.num // <--- Error
    }
}
```

It would be nice, if the *properties and signals* defined uppon instantiation would be available as `parent.propertyName` to the Objects added by a `default`-property aswell, I think.
Is there a way (to maybe hack this)?

Comment: I really struggled with the title of this question. If you have a better suggest it via *edit* or *comment* please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

What you can do is stop assuming the outer scope in QML code is always the parent.

You could either access it directly by id:

```
MyComp {
    id: myComp
    signal sig1()
    property int num: 5
    Button {
        text: myComp.num
        onClicked: myComp.sig1()
    }
}
```

Or if the object you want to access is the root item, you can access its properties implicitely:

```
MyComp {
    signal sig1()
    property int num: 5
    Button {
        text: num
        onClicked: sig1()
    }
}
```

One good practice (albeit maybe too extreme for most case) that can be deduced from this situation, is to only use `parent` when you actually want to access the parent `Item` in the visual hierarchy, for things like `anchors` or `width` and `height`.

Comment: That is sad :-(. I myself am (trying) to follow this *good practice* already. But for reusable components it would have been nice to have something like: `default context: someID` that you could - but not must - set to the same object you reference with `default property alias blub: someID.data` or similar.